# pointer to a const pointer to an int

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

Can some one explain me a point in my following program 
The following program i wrote to understand what is meant by int * const *  var;

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std ;

int main(){

int a = 2;

int  * const   x = &a;
int * const * p = &x;

cout << **p;
return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is 2  .

My point of concern is p is pointer to a constant pointer to an int which is how i am using it , but i always studied that to store a pointer you need pointer to a pointer . How is this program working then . Should'nt i have used

```
int * const **P
```

as this would mean P could be containing address of some pointer .

I dont know why my code works :)

Comment: `p` is already a pointer to pointer. Just **look at its declaration.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- to store a pointer you need pointer to a pointer

Apparently you think that `const` pointer is somehow not a pointer. You are wrong. `const` is just indicator of immutability.
Therefore pointer to `const` pointer *is* pointer to pointer

Answer (score 7):

1. `int * const` is a "`const` pointer to an `int`".
2. `int * const *` is a "pointer to a `const` pointer to an `int`".

Type 2 *is* a pointer to a pointer. More specifically, it's a pointer to a `const` pointer. That's great, because the pointer you want to point to (`x`) is `const`. Since `x` is of type 1, taking the address of it gives you a pointer of type 2.

`int * const **` would be a "pointer to pointer to `const` pointer to `int`". Count how many "pointer"s there are. Three! In fact, that's what you would get if you were to take the address of `p` with `&p`.

Comment: @SohamChowdhury Pointers quickly become second nature with a little bit of practice. I have little boxes with arrows pointing between them in my head.

Comment: But remember, as soon as you can see three stars, it's time for a day of rest.

Comment: @DanielFischer "By the seventh day God had used a pointer to a pointer to a pointer; so on the seventh day he rested from all his work. Then God blessed the seventh day and made it holy, because on it he rested from all the indirection he had done." - Pretty sure that's how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is of type `int* const` and suppose `x` be of type some `ABC`.
so pointer to `x` is declared as `ABC *p=&x;`

which is equivalent to `int* const *p=&x;`

Answer (score -1):

I think this helps in intuiting the statement.
substitute the `*` with `pointer` and read the statement backwards.